# Wobbly frames & windows in Java Swing?

Tags: java, linux, swing, java-2d, java-3d

I was wondering if it's possible to implement Compiz's [wobbly windows](http://www.ozzyfrank.com/Ubuntu/images/ubuntu_beryl_wobble2.jpg) graphic effect (deforming a window while moving it using the mouse cursor) in Java Swing, using Java2D or Java3D.  Has anyone thought about this before?

Answer (score 1):

When running Compiz or similar, Swing is affected by this. You don't need to implement this specifically.

Comment: Same for Mac OS X minimize with [genie effect](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0o_BB_GCk1A).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, using the new (Java 7) translucency API. You would have to paint the whole thing all by yourself though... :)
As someone noted before - leave that to Compiz... :)

Comment: Yeah but my point is implementing it in Java, so any java App I create will have java wobbly frames ( cross platform ), not the compiz wobbly frames